# Stopping the Android Soft Keyboard flashing black switching activities

Tags: android, caching, android-layout, android-listview

I'm working on an app and have a small problem when the soft keyboard is shown before switching activities. This happens when:

1. The user hits the search button
2. They enter a search term, view the search in a new activity and then return to the previous page
3. When the user returns to the previous page, a black box flashes where the soft keyboard was and then returns to normal

[image: Steps]

If the list is turned off or empty this problem never manifests. I have tried to enable caching of the listview children, hiding the listview when the activity pauses but to no avail. I would really appreciate any insight into why this might be occuring.

Thanks,
Laurence

Comment: Is this the platform search, or your own search bar? And are you seeing this on a device, the emulator, or both?

Comment: Platform search and have tried on both emulator & device. Thanks

Comment: Might be worth noting on the device its less noticeable than on the emulator.

Comment: That's probably just the CPU/GPU speed difference, as devices are faster than the emulator. Try temporarily removing your `ImageView` from the rows. If the problem goes away, then your issue is probably that the rows are a bit slow to render (e.g., Android is resizing images to thumbnails on the fly), in which case working on boosting your row performance may clear up the issue.

Comment: I just tried simplifying the row to a single TextView, still flashed black. I wonder if it has something to do with using a CursorAdapter, any thoughts on this?

Comment: I would not expect the adapter type to have an impact, though I confess that I am stumped. If you can create a sample project that demonstrates this effect and make it available, I'd like to take a peek at it.

Comment: I have created a very small project and stuck it up on Github. If you repeat the steps above, the black flicker is displayed when the user moves from the new search activity to the previous activity. [Link to source](https://github.com/laurencedawson/SampleFlicker)

Comment: I can reproduce your problem. OTOH, I think I see the same thing with the built-in Contacts application, though it is less obvious due to the dark theme. I suspect that this just "is what it is". BTW, one of my samples (using an ArrayAdapter) also exhibits this behavior, so it is not adapter-specific.

Comment: Ah. Well thanks for trying it with another adapter too. I think the best solution is just to set the window color in the onStart method of an activity (setting in a style causes adverse startup side effects). This makes the flash far less noticeable, would be interesting to see if the problem also occurs when hardware acceleration is enabled.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I have a problem similar to this, that I described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18669033/why-an-activity-is-trying-to-open-the-softkeyboard-jb-bug. Still, no one answered... Do you have any clues of what could be happening? This problem began for me with JB, no problem prior to 4.0.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought I'd follow up.

This problem was specific to pre Android 3.0 devices. On HC, ICS and JB this is no longer exhibited. As simple way to get around this on older versions of Android is to just change the windows background to match the color of your view. It still is blanked out but no where near as noticeable as black on white.